# How can I take screenshot of some specific area using javascript in chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, screenshot

I am working on a chrome extension in which I want to take screenshot of only specific portion of the current window, not the entire window itself.
For now,I have been using this API of chrome

```
chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab(null,{},function(dataUri){
            // datauri is the screenshot
        });
```

It takes the screenshot of entire page but I want screenshot of my given x,y  coordinates.
How can I achieve the same?
Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 3):

One possible approach would be:

1. Use [`CanvasRenderingContext2D.drawImage(image, sx, sy, sWidth, sHeight, dx, dy, dWidth, dHeight)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage) to draw the screenshot onto the canvas, in the meanwhile making use of corresponding parameters to crop the image
2. Use [`HTMLCanvasElement.toDataURL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL) to convert canvas to [data URI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/data_URIs) containing a representation of the image, or [`CanvasRenderingContext2D.getImageData()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/getImageData) to return an [ImageData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageData) object, it depends on your needs.

Sample code (**Please be aware depending on your needs, you may want to move inner logic to content scripts**):

```
chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab(null, {}, function(dataUri) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function() {
        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        canvas.width = WIDTH;
        canvas.height = HEIGHT;
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        // Assuming px,py as starting coordinates and hx,hy be the width and the height of the image to be extracted
        context.drawImage(img, px, py, hx, hy, 0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        var croppedUri = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
        // You could deal with croppedUri as cropped image src.
    };
    img.src = dataUri;
});
```

Comment: Could you share a demo example for my case assuming px,py as starting coordinates  and hx,hy be the width and the height of the image to be extracted?